# Dplyr mutate new column value as na when other column equals na

Tags: r, dplyr

I am using `mutate(quarter_date = paste0(substring(year(DATE),1,4),"-0",quarter(DATE)))` in order to get the quarter and year of my `DATE` column. However when the date column is `NA` I am getting `NA-0NA`. Is it possible to make values in `quarter_date` `NA` when they are `NA` in the `DATE` column?

Example:

```
    DATE    QUARTER_DATE
 2021-03-04     2021-01
     NA          NA-0NA
```

What I would like:

```
    DATE    QUARTER_DATE
 2021-03-04     2021-01
     NA           NA
```

Comment: `mutate(quarter_date = ifelse(is.na(DATE), NA, paste0(substring(year(DATE),1,4),"-0",quarter(DATE))))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```
 dplyr::tibble(DATE = c(lubridate::today(), NA)) %>%
 dplyr::mutate(QUARTER_DATE = lubridate::floor_date(DATE, "quarter") %>% format( "%Y-%m"))
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  DATE       QUARTER_DATE
  <date>     <chr>       
1 2021-03-23 2021-01     
2 NA         NA
```